# npm hangs forever when installing ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I'm having trouble installing the Ionic Framework through npm. I set up the proxy using cntlm and everything works fine, I can install all the other modules I wanted (yeoman, bower grunt, the usual stuff :) ). But somehow npm hangs when it comes to installing Ionic...I have a log ouput that shows where npm keeps hanging without throwing any kind of error:

```
npm sill gunzTarPerm extractEntry node_modules/wrappy/test/basic.js
npm sill gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'node_modules/wrappy/test/basic.js', 420, 4
38 ]
npm sill gunzTarPerm extractEntry node_modules/write-file-atomic/package.json
npm sill gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'node_modules/write-file-atomic/package.jso
n', 420, 438 ]
npm sill gunzTarPerm extractEntry node_modules/write-file-atomic/.npmignore
npm sill gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'node_modules/write-file-atomic/.npmignore'
, 420, 438 ]
npm sill gunzTarPerm extractEntry node_modules/write-file-atomic/README.md
npm sill gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'node_modules/write-file-atomic/README.md',
 420, 438 ]
npm sill gunzTarPerm extractEntry node_modules/write-file-atomic/LICENSE
npm sill gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'node_modules/write-file-atomic/LICENSE', 4
20, 438 ]
npm sill gunzTarPerm extractEntry node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js
npm sill gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js',
420, 438 ]
npm sill gunzTarPerm extractEntry node_modules/write-file-atomic/test/basic.js
npm sill gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'node_modules/write-file-atomic/test/basic.
js', 420, 438 ]
npm sill addBundled read tarball     
npm sill cleanup remove extracted module
loadRequestedDeps ? netwo ¯ ¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦
```

The stupid thing is, I already had it up and running but it took hours of try and error and somehow at some point it worked I think it had something to do with node-gyp or python...

Comment: I face the same issue. Did you reached any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

[This Github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10197) solved it for me, by upgrading to the latest version of NodeJS.

Basically, you are facing this issue because of an incompatibility between the version of NodeJS you have installed on your marchine, and the Ionic version you are installing.